# does jquery has a ajax function similar to Prototype's Ajax.periodcalUpdater?

Tags: jquery

I need to update html page periodically by the data from server, but couldn't find a Jquery ajax function to do that, any suggestion? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You should use setInterval().

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_setinterval.asp

```
setInterval(ajaxFunction, 5000);
```

Comment: Actually, `setInterval(ajaxFunction, 5000);`, very important difference there ;)